# Amanda error: won't eject tape

Tags: amanda

Im trying to load some new media into my antique tape system. Running this command:

> amtape ARCHIVE eject

gives me this response:

> amtape: slot 6 not ejected: Unloading Data Transfer Element into Storage Element 6...mtx: Request Sense: Long Report=yes

I'm not finding any way to get this 'long report'. Suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution( in this case ):

1. run 'top'
2. notice that `taper` and `chunker` are running even though `amdump` isn't
3. `init 6` machine
4. try `eject` command again

Notice that it works now. Apply palm to forehead.